# Mac Address using java Giving NULL

Tags: java, cmd

I am using a command for finding mac address .. I don't know why It's giving me a null value.

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

public class GetMc 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Mac Address : "+getMac());
    }

    public static String getMac() throws IOException 
    {
        String [] result = {"NULL","NULL"};
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getmac /fo scv/nh");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        if(!in.ready())
        {
            System.out.println("Empty Buffer");
        }

        String line;
        line = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);

        if(line!=null)
        {
            result = line.split(",");
        }

        return result[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use native java - http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-mac-address-in-java/

Comment: I want to run it in java 4 .. Just trying .. But what is the Problem actually?? in this command??

Comment: Is this command working when ran from CMD? Because I'm getting an error when running "getmac /fo scv/nh"

Comment: If I m using just getmac in cmd it's working!! .. So should I just write "getmac" in exec()??

Comment: If I write Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getmac"); only , then also it's giving me a null value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this and make sure that `getmac` is working on command propmpt when you hit directly

```
public static String getMac() throws IOException 
    {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getmac /fo csv /nh");
    java.io.BufferedReader in = new java.io.BufferedReader(new  java.io.InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    line = in.readLine();        
    String[] result = line.split(",");

    System.out.println(result[0].replace('"', ' ').trim());
    return result[0].replace('"', ' ').trim();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getmac /fo csv /nh");
```

Works for me

Comment: It seems without the format option, the result is not written to process output  streams.

Comment: This also giving an empty buffer!! :(

Comment: Which Version are you running? I'm getting result on Windows 7

Comment: I am using windows XP.The problem is the command "getmac /fo csv /nh" is working is cmd.But, when I use it in java program then it gives me an empty buffer.

Comment: Sorry buddy, don't have an XP host to check it.. :(